# VBA SendKey Events Happening Out of Order

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a simple script to copy and paste cell values manually.
I know that I can do this by other means, but I would like to use the SendKeys.

Here is my script to copy cell A1 into A2:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub my_copy()

  Range("A1").Select
  SendKeys "^c"
  Sleep 10
  Range("A2").Select
  SendKeys "~"
  Sleep 10

End Sub
```

I can't seem to figure out how to correct the issue I'm having. It selects cell A1, then waits, then A2, then copies and pastes. (Instead of copying after A1 is selected)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
Range("A2") = Range("A1")
```

Where A2 is a copy of A1.
If you want to use sendkeys, I'd do this:

```
Range("A1").Select
SendKeys "^c", True
Range("A2").Select
SendKeys "^V", True 'I'm a Windows user
```

The true means wait, but that's the format for Excel VBA.

Comment: After adding ",True" to the end of the SendKeys statements. It seems to be working in order now

Answer (score 0):

icebird76 is correct, however you can still use your "~" to send an "Enter".  This means you won't keep Cell A1 selected as the copied cell.

```
Range("A1").Select
SendKeys "^c", True
Range("A2").Select
SendKeys "~", True
```

There's more info on how the SendKeys Statement works and the requirement for "True" here.... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655.aspx